# convector hot water radiator in far bedroom doesnt work on second floor

Tags: radiator

far bedroom radiator isnt warm while other rooms convector radiator works fine. cant find any valves in basement or near radiator. any assistance would be greatly appreciated.all pipes leading and exiting are cold.
all other radiators work properly. i dont see any valves near it and when i bled it, no air or water was in it

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Can you add some details (like model numbers, pictures, etc) to your question? We won't be able to help you without you adding that with an [edit].

Comment: Is every other radiator working properly?  What is the pressure in the boiler?  Did it work last year or is this a new problem?A picture of the bedroom radiator and piping would be helpful. Also, a picture of the boiler.

Comment: all other radiators work properly. i dont see any valves near it and when i bled it, no air or water was in it